# Can I build a system that would swap a set of tokens and then transfer them between two addresses?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap

I'm hoping to build a system that would let me, in one transaction, transfer ETH from WalletA and receive DAI in Wallet B.

Is there a contract out there that currently does it? or is it even possible to build a contract that does this?

Keep in mind the `toToken`, `fromToken`, `walletB` addresses would all be parameters on a given function call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can directly interact with UniswapV3 or Sushiswap router contracts to swap ETH to DAI and send that to a particular receiver address.

Here's the example with Sushiswap (UniswapV2) router:

[image: function-ss]

1. payableAmount: ETH amount you want to swap
2. path: [WETH, DAI]
3. to: `walletB`